# how to execute js script file as child process node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have a problem, I'm trying to execute file that sending mail using nodemailer and I need to execute it from another JS file I tried to do it like this:

```
const  exec  = require('child_process').exec;
       exec('"C:/Users/NikitaSeliverstov/node_modules/.bin/send.js"');
```

but mail is not sending. I don't need to send params the file send.js just sending text file with fully specified path . Sorry for obvious question but I can't figure it out.
Also I tried to do it like this:

```
 const  exec  = require('child_process').exec;
        exec('"node C:/Users/NikitaSeliverstov/node_modules/.bin/send.js"');
```

Comment: can you show what error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not having any err

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to specify a callback function which will be called after your exec command is executed:

i created 2 files:

**anotherTest.js**

```
console.log('another test');
```

**test.js**

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

const child = exec('node anotherTest.js',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
});
```

this is the output:

```
stdout: another test

stderr:
```

you run the test.js script by doing "**node test.js**" in the terminal/console. you can change the arguments of the exec command with the arguments that you want.

Comment: That's works thank you. So the problem is that without callback it won't work?

Comment: yup. You need to define a callback function whenever you need to perform an asynchronous operation. Or else, the code wont wait for the operation to complete.

Comment: depending on the node version that you're on, you can replace/wrap callbacks with promises and async await.

Comment: glad i could help.